# In Scala, given a subclass, how to check if it overrides the default method of its parent interface (defined in Java) using reflection?

Tags: java, scala, reflection

```
(defined in Java)
interface Foo {
  default int bar() {
    throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
  }
}

(defined in Scala)
class FooImpl extends Foo {
  override int bar() {
    return 42;
  }
}
```

In the above code snippet, I have an interface defined in Java, with a default method `bar` which just throws exception. The question is how to check if a subclass `FooImpl` overrides the default method or not. It seems in Java we can check the declaring class on the `Method` instance from reflection: if `FooImpl` overrides the method, the declaring class will be itself, and otherwise will be the interface `Foo`.

However above seems not true in Scala (2.12): in both situations the declaring class will be `FooImpl`.

Comment: Why would you want to know? You can always check the method name and parameter types following the normal override rules.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I was checking this in Scala - I was assuming that Java and Scala should have the same behavior regarding this but apparently this is not true. In Java it seems I can easily check this by using `Method.getDeclaringClass` but in Scala the declaring class are always the same.

Answer (score 2):

For example if I have something like this:

```
interface Test {
    default void go() {

    }
}

static class Impl implements Test, AutoCloseable {

    @Override
    public void go() {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

I can find out if `Method m` is the one you are looking for by:

```
 private static boolean isDefaultAndOverridden(Method m, Class<?> cls) {

    Class<?>[] interfaces = ClassUtils.getAllInterfacesForClass(cls);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(interfaces));


    return Arrays.stream(interfaces)
                 .flatMap(in -> Arrays.stream(in.getDeclaredMethods()))
                 .filter(Method::isDefault)
                 .filter(method -> method.getName().equals(m.getName()))
                 .filter(method -> method.getReturnType() == m.getReturnType())
                 .filter(method -> Arrays.equals(method.getParameterTypes(), m.getParameterTypes()))
                 .count() == 1;

}
```

I am using `ClassUtils` from `Spring` to get all the interfaces that a class implements, direct or not. There are many libraries that exposes such functionality also (but it's not that complicated to write it yourself)

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry that I forgot to mention I was using Scala and seems it has different behavior regarding default methods from parent interfaces. Will edit my question. It seems with Java we can also check `Method.getDeclaringClass`.

Answer (score 1):

`.getDeclarignClass` seems to work fine for me.

Here is what I did.
In java:

```
interface Foo {
   default String bar() {
      return "bar";
   }
   default String baz() {
     return "baz";
   }
}
```

In scala:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    override def bar() = "baz"
}

object Bar {
    def main(argv: Array[String]) = classOf[Bar]
      .getMethods.filter(_.getName.startsWith("ba"))
      .map { m => m.getName -> m.getDeclaringClass.getName }
      .foreach(println)
}
```

This prints:

```
(bar,Bar)
(baz,Foo)
```

So, something like this should work:

```
    def isOverridden(mtd: Method, clazz: Class) = 
       mtd.getDeclaringClass == clazz
```

Comment: Thanks. Hmm I tried this but for me it returns `Bar` for both case. Which version of Scala you were using? I wonder what could cause the difference.

Comment: Both 2.13 and 2.12 work correctly. I highly doubt it has anything to do with scala version, as this method is java's native implementation.

Comment: Strange. This never works for me. I had the same code setup in a simple Maven project and it always print Bar for both bar and baz method.

Comment: Try doing it outside of your project. Just paste the snippets I showed above into two files, compile and run from command line without maven or anything. If _that_ doesn't work, I wanna ask what jdk you are using :/

Comment: I tried - it is still the same. I tried both JDK 8 and 11 BTW.